# What does Keycloak Java Adapter property "public-client" mean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-services

According to Keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_java_adapter_config), the Java Adapter has property named `public-client` described as

> If set to true, the adapter will not send credentials for the client to Keycloak

What does this "will not send credentials to Keycloak" actually mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Keycloak you can set a client to be public or confidential (or bearer-only):

[image]

From the [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/client-types/) one can read:

> OAuth defines two types of clients: confidential clients and public
> clients.
>
> Confidential clients are applications that are able to securely
> authenticate with the authorization server, for example being able to
> keep their registered client secret safe.
>
> **Public clients are unable to use registered client secrets**, such as
> applications running in a browser or on a mobile device.

And in more detail from [source](https://auth0.com/docs/applications/confidential-and-public-applications) one can read:

> According to the OAuth 2.0 spec, applications can be classified as
> either confidential or public. **The main difference relates to whether
> or not the application is able to hold credentials (such as a client
> ID and secret) securely.** This affects the type of authentication the
> applications can use.

> **Confidential applications can hold credentials in a secure way without exposing them to unauthorized parties.**

If the client is confidential, then it will contain a client secret:

[image]

> What does this "will not send credentials to Keycloak"

In means that in the requests that client secret will not be sent.